why does BIOS print out the letter "U" before a keypress in assembly x86
I'm trying to get the user input and store the character in a variable, but the problem with that is that whenever I run boot.bin it outputs the letter "U" before any key is pressed. Does anyone have a similar problem? Here is the bios output:
[org 0x7c00]

char:
    db 0

loop:
    mov ah, 0
    int 0x16

    mov [char], al
    
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, [char]
    int 0x10

    jmp loop

jmp $
times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55, 0xaa


Don't put your data (char: db 0) in the execution path. Move it to before the times line.

Execution starts from char:  db 0 which is not what you want.
